# Warning when trying to view Dataframe: "Random.seed has wrong length"

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, rstudio, random-seed

As I try to view a data in RStudio, R puts out a warning saying (this happens for every dataframe):

> > View(d)
> >     Warning in View :
> >      '.Random.seed' is not an integer vector but of type 'double', so ignored
> >     Error in View : '.Random.seed' has wrong length

I wanted to add that once my laptop had a problem and some programs were uninstalled. Everything worked fine with R and RStudio before this problem . 
After it, I had to install some things new and my laptop's still working, but how i mentioned I have this problem when loading a dataframe.
Almost all the other things with RStudio are working. I can use functions and stuff like that.

Thanks for your help.